# Name of this Tree/Plant

Tags: plant-care

I bought this Tree/Plant from nursery but dont know the name in English. It has sweet fragrance to it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be Ruta graveolens see [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_graveolens) for more details on the plant.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with George of all trades. It looks like a young ruta. Is the smell very strong when you brush up against it?

Comment: Yes when i brush up against it has sweet-ish kind of smell